# Javascript проблема с intput

Tags: javascript, html

Новичок в javascript, пытаюсь написать маленький код для расчета расходов.
Мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на клавишу рассчитать, выполнялось сразу 3 функции и выводило значения в поля результатов. Ошибок в консоле нет , в чем может быть проблема, уже переписывал код несколько раз ... заранее спасибо за помощь.

```js
var a = document.getElementById('a').value,
  b = document.getElementById('b').value,
  c = document.getElementById('c').value,
  d = document.getElementById('d').value,
  e = document.getElementById('e').value,
  f = document.getElementById('f').value,
  g = document.getElementById('g').value,
  h = document.getElementById('h').value,
  i = document.getElementById('i').value,
  salary = document.getElementById('salary').value,
  days = document.getElementById('days').value,
  total = document.getElementById('total').value,
  balance = document.getElementById('balance').value,
  allow = document.getElementById('allow').value;


function all() {
  summ();
  minus();
  division();
};

function summ() {
  total = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b) + parseFloat(c) + parseFloat(d) + parseFloat(e) + parseFloat(f) + parseFloat(g) + parseFloat(h) + parseFloat(i);
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;
};

function minus() {
  balance = parseFloat(salary) - parseFloat(total);
  document.getElementById('balance').innerHTML = balance;
};

function division() {
  allow = parseFloat(balance) / parseFloat(days);
  document.getElementById('allow').innerHTML = balance;
};
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  Сколько вы платите за квартиру ?
  <input id="a" type="number" name="flat">
  </br>
  </br>
  Сколько отложить денег на продукты ?
  <input id="b" type="number" name="products" value="">
  </br>
  </br>
  Сколько отложить денег на дорогу?
  <input id="c" type="number" name="road" value="">
  </br>
  </br>
  Сколько отложить денег на оплату за интернет ?
  <input id="d" type="number" name="internet" value="">
  </br>
  </br>
  Сколько нужно платить за подписки и прочее ?
  <input id="e" type="number" name="subscribe" value="">
  </br>
  </br>
  Сколько отложить 10% от зп ?
  <input id="f" type="number" name="percent" value="">
  </br>
  </br>
  Сколько отложить в резерв ?
  <input id="g" type="number" name="reserve" value="">
  </br>
  </br>
  Сколько отложить в копилку ?
  <input id="h" type="number" name="moneyBox" value="">
  </br>
  </br>
  Сколько оставить на карманные расходы ?
  <input id="i" type="number" name="pocketExpenses" value="">
  </br>
  </br>
  Сколько у вас аванс / зарплата ?
  <input id="salary" type="number" name="salary" value="">
  </br>
  </br>
  Сколько дней осталось до ЗП / Аванса ?
  <input id="days" type="number" name="days" value="">
  <hr>
  </br>
  <h3 align="center">Результат</h3>
  <hr> Сумма ваших затрат:
  <input id="total" type="text" name="q1" value="" readonly>
  </br>
  </br>
  Остаток после расходов:
  <input id="balance" type="text" name="q2" value="" readonly>
  </br>
  </br>
  Разрешено потратить в день:
  <input id="allow" type="text" name="q3" value="" readonly>
  </br>
  </br>
  <button id="count" onclick="all()">Рассчитать</button>
  <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Слишком много ошибок, чтобы комментировать все. Для начала замените все `</br>` на `<br/>`, а потом переименуйте функцию `all` в любую другую. Например `calc`

Comment: `document.getElementById('balance').innerHTML = balance;` баоанс у вас инпут, посмотрите какие методи есть у инпута и только потом начинайте писать вопроси...

Comment: Что касается тега br, этот набросок был сделан для примера.

В итоге сменил имя функции , почитал про методы input, сменил метод, немного кое-где поменял кое-что,  теперь все благополучно работает.

Большое спасибо за ваши ответы!

Answer (score 0):

1 ошибка - не называйте функцию all(). напишите, например, calc()
2 ошибка - переменные надо получать внутри функции либо передавать их как параметры функции

Comment: Спасибо большое, исправил, все работает!